# why output values of linear transformation are wrong?

Tags: logarithms, linear-transformations, exponential-function, mathematical-modeling

I am going to fit my data using an equation, Y=a*(1-e^(-bx))^c equation. 
a & c are the intercept and slope, b is given.

Here are the steps I did:

```
1. I transformed Y=a*(1-e^(-bx))^c equation into log(Y)=log(a)+c*log(1-e^(-bx))
2. solved intercept and slope: 
   log(a)+c =log(Y)/log(1-e^(-0.3*x) (b=0.3)
3. fitted linear model log(a)+c VS log(x)
4. extracted intercept and slope: a=5.19 & c=-2.15 
5. replaced them into original equation like this. 
   Y=5.19*(1-e^(-0.3)*x))^(-2.51).
```

Here is main issue, when I use this equation for my data, output gives me wrong values. So can you check the steps whether they are right or not? It seems right, but....

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this $$y=a(1-e^{-bx})^c$$?

Comment: Your step 2 seems wrong. You can't divide by $\log a + c$ to remove it from the RHS (it isn't a factor). You would have to subtract $\log a$ and then divide by $c$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Transform $Y=a(1-e^{-bx})^c$ equation into $\log(Y)=\log(a)+c\log(1-e^{-bx})$ assuming both $Y$ and $1-\exp(-bx)$ are both positive.
2. Fit linear model $\log(Y)$ againts $\log(1-e^{-bx})$ since $b$ has been given to you.  $\log(a)$ is the intercept and $c$ is the slope.
3. compute $a$ to be exponential of the intercept and $c$ is the slope and plot the original graph using these values.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried this one bur still not correct answer. I just guess that I need to de-transform a and c to replace them into main equation because I obtained a & c from log equation. It seems they can't be replaced directly into exp equation. But I am not sure. what do you think?

Comment: are the assumptions that $Y$ and $1-\exp(-bx)$ are both positive holds? how do you know the valus are not correct? (btw, I am sleeping soon, might not reply immediately). what are you trying to optimize?

Comment: hi? I just back. no, they are both have negative values.  log.Y has some negative,  and all the values of log(1-exp(-bx)) are negative. I knew the correct answer from professor.

Comment: logarithm being evaluated to be negative is fine. Did you remember to take exponential for the intercept? is the slope value wrong too? you might like to check with your prof if the answer is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

If so, then we get $$\log(y)=\log(a)+c\log(1-e^{-bx})$$

Comment: Yes, this is the 1st step I did. Now I want to fit this equation for my data and find out intercept and slope in the steps from 2 to 5. I am not so sure if they are right